# Laravel 4 - pagination filter reults

Tags: filter, laravel-4, pagination

Does anybody know why I have an error when I'm using the Laravel pagination after filter results in a View?

It works perfectly in my simple view, but when I filter data using the form I've created for... the same pagination doesn't work!

MY CODE:

Controller:

```
public function filtro()
{
    $keyword = Input::get('keyword');
    $asignatura = Input::get('asignatura_id');
    $nivel = Input::get('nivel_id');

    $actividades = Actividad::where('actividad', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%');

    if($asignatura){
        $actividades->where('asignatura_id', $asignatura);                                                              
    }
    if($nivel){
        $actividades->where('nivel_id', $nivel);
    }

    $actividads = $actividades->orderBy('created_at', 'DES')
                            ->paginate(10);



    $id_user = Sentry::getUser()->id;
    $fichas = Ficha::where('user_id', $id_user)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
    $asignatura_clave = Asignatura::where('id', $asignatura)->first();
    $asignatura_id = Asignatura::orderBy('nombre', 'asc')->lists('nombre','id');
    $nivel_id = Nivel::orderBy('edad', 'asc')->lists('edad','id');
    $nivel_clave = Nivel::where('id', $nivel)->first();

    $user = User::find($id_user);
    // Devuelve todas las actividades que estan relacionadas con alguna ficha.
    $actividadEnFicha = Actividad::has('fichas')
                                ->get();

    //$asignaturas = Asignatura::all();
    // return var_dump($actividadEnFicha);
    return View::make('actividads.index')
                    ->with('fichas', $fichas)
                    ->with('user', $user)
                    ->with('palabra_clave', $keyword)
                    ->with('keyword', $keyword)
                    ->with('nivel_id', $nivel_id)
                    ->with('nivel_clave', $nivel_clave)
                    ->with('asignatura_clave', $asignatura_clave)
                    ->with('asignatura_id', $asignatura_id)
                    ->with('actividadEnFicha', $actividadEnFicha)
                    ->with('actividads', $actividads);//->with('asignaturas', $asignaturas);
}
```

The pagination code in my View:

```
{{ $actividads->links(); }}
```

MESSAGE ERROR:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException

* @param array $others
* @return void
*
* @throws \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
*/
protected function methodNotAllowed(array $others)
{
throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException($others);
}
```

**EDIT:**

I've created these two routes 
`Route::post('filtro', array('as' => 'filtro', 'uses' => 'ActividadController@filtro'));` and `Route::get('filtro', array('as' => 'filtro', 'uses' => 'ActividadController@filtro'));` , and pagination works.

The problem now is when I change to another page (using pagination) my filters are forgotten and it paginates all my activities angain... :S Any idea why? This is the first time I try it, and probably I'm doing it in a wrong way.

Any idea what's happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Please write the code causing the problem

Comment: I have already edited my post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two remarques, the first is that inside the `if` you should assign the new result. Second is in the `orderBy` the second parameter should be `'DESC'` and not `'DES'`. And I think this second error is causing your issue.

```
if($asignatura){
    $actividades = $actividades->where('asignatura_id', $asignatura);                                                              
}
if($nivel){
    $actividades = $actividades->where('nivel_id', $nivel);
}

$actividads = $actividades->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                        ->paginate(10);
```

Hope this fixes your problem

**Edit**

The `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` is usualy caused by a route not allowing some type of requests. the paginate links sends the page number to the action using `GET` and I guess you're not allowing `GET` in your routes for this method.

Comment: Nop @webNeat, I've fixed the 'DESC', but it wasn't the problem... :(

Comment: Can do dump the variable `$actividades` ? and do you got some errors ?

Comment: I mean... the pagination works apparently. You can see the numers: 1,2,3,4,... But, when you click to change the page, it doesn't work, and shows an error page.

Comment: Can you copy the error and add it to your question ?

Comment: Sorry... you have now the error message in the post!

Comment: Thank you very much!! It was the route! You're right ;)

Comment: I've created these two routes `Route::post('filtro', array('as' => 'filtro', 'uses' => 'ActividadController@filtro'));` and `Route::get('filtro', array('as' => 'filtro', 'uses' => 'ActividadController@filtro'));`, and pagination works. The problem is when I change to another page (using pagination) my filters are forgotten and it paginates all my activities angain... :S Any idea why? This is the first time I try it, and probably I'm doing it in a wrong way.

Comment: First never give the same name to two different routes. Secondly, Pagination uses `GET` if you want to keep filters you should use `GET` for your action too. So use only `GET` route for this method.

Comment: I had already tried it. But there is any problem with that route too, because if I only use `GET`, my form to filter results doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem with pagination using `session`.

My problem was that, when I changed the page by pagination, everything was reloaded and my filters were forgotten. So I created a `session` for every filter and now I can move through my filtered data by pagination.